# How to take screenshots of an app window in linux with python

Tags: python

I'm using python3 and i want to screenshot my virtual machine screen.
I need to open some windows in the virtual machine enviroment, after that i have to analize the screenshot with opencv but i don't know how to get the window position, it's width and it's height. I have to do that in linux os. There is a way for take the position of any app window opened on the pc?

Comment: Is this window going to be moving? What have you tried to use before?

Comment: This window is not going to move. I have found how to do it in windows but for linux didn't find so much

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use wxPython. Here's an example of how you might use it to take a screenshot:

```
import wx

wx.App()  # Need to create an App instance before doing anything
screen = wx.ScreenDC()
size = screen.GetSize()
bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
del mem  # Release bitmap
bmp.SaveFile('screenshot.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Comment: But how it detects where the virtual machine window is?